# How to integrate Dropzonejs with wordpress WP REST API?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, meteor, dropzone.js, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Meteor application that shares some data with a WordPress site. 
How can I set up a dropzone uploader on the Meteor app that posts to the WordPress REST API?

I already have the api integrated with the Meteor app and have authentication working. I'm trying to POST to the /media endpoint on the WordPress site, but I can't figure out how to get the file data from dropzone to post to wordpress.

I'm getting this error on the meteor server:

```
Error: failed [500] [{"code":"json_upload_sideload_error","message":"Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons."}]
```

Comment: is the meteor app and the wordpress site on different domains?

Comment: They are different domains.

Comment: then the error you're getting makes sense: "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons"... maybe find another way to manage the files?

Comment: Already took care of cors and authentication.

Comment: its related to cors but not really. the server you're sending to (i'm unsure of your wordpress site) is saying that it doesn't match with .* files you want to send. so you'll need to modify the server to take specific files.... which if you're using wp-rest-api it seems unlikely that you can modify that server file

Comment: Just to clarify I actually do have access to the WordPress sites sever also. and the files are all .jpg, .png, etc. Given that the api has a media endpoint designed to accept media files I would think those should be accepted file types, unless this needs to be changed at a higher level somewhere?

Comment: http://wp-api.org/#media_create-an-attachment

Comment: is your server setup to accept (not wordpress the actual server itself) other files?

Comment: I'm not sure, How could I figure that out? I have ssh access